# in live Hadoop cluster - Migrating data from on Prem to cloud without copying

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, hadoop, cloud

In LIVE hadoop cluster How to migrate data from on prem to cloud without copying data from prem to cloud, since the data size is more than 1 petabyte. If we do it with copying then due to network bandwidth, the transfer will take few weeks.
Suppose there are 40 data nodes in cluster at Location A, and we want to move data to cloud with Data center located at Location B. Data is replicated with replication factor of 3.
My solution will be adding 5 cloud nodes in cluster every day and stopping 2 on prem nodes per day, after that running balancer. Assuming data will balanced in 1 day, then it will take atleast 20 days for entire cluster to migrate to cloud.

I am trying to figure out other way, also if anyone can correct me on my plan.

Thanks

Comment: You're still copying data blocks by replicating... AWS has a service called Snowball where they ship you a hard drive, and then you copy data to it, and ship it back. Then you're not paying network bandwidth fees

Comment: Snowball is for 80 tb data i guess, they have snowmobile also for larger data. But these are limited to certain locations also. I am asking if architecturally if we can migrate data from one cluster to another without any downtime.

Comment: I've personally never tried this, so I can't really say. But I'm thinking about how you would transition the namenode to the new cluster and have external clients be redirected to a completely new network space with no downtime? You might want to look at HDFS federation or ViewFS as a temporary solution